# Is there a bug with link-following?

Tags: bug

If I follow the link in the answer to this question, it closes the current tab and opens the link in a new tab. This is with the current version of Firefox.

[What is the best time to implement Multiplayer system?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/182364/what-is-the-best-time-to-implement-multiplayer-system/182366)

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: So you can't hit the "back" button?

Comment: Hm.... I'm not able to reproduce this in Firefox 76.0 / 76.0.1 or in Chrome 81.0.4044.138, both 64-bit on Windows 10. The link opens in the same tab for me, and my back button lets me return to the answer.

Comment: No, the back button is grayed out. "Undo close tab" restores the GDSE tab, leaving the Steam tab open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firefox extension "Facebook Container" causes this behavior. So there's no issue with the site itself, I don't think.

Comment: Good find! May I ask how you tracked down the cause?

Comment: I remembered that in the right click menu it's not "open in new tab" it's "open in new Facebook tab" referring to that plugin. I thought then that maybe that plugin was causing the issue. So I turned it off, and the problem was fixed.